# How to return value of table joined as array object in array in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel-5

I have 2 tables:
**orders**(order_id,order_code,user_id,full_name,phone,address,recieve_address,total_product,total_price,status,created_at,updated_at)

**detail_order**(id,order_id,order_code,product_id,price,quantity,total_amount,created_at,updated_at)

How to write query to return the value of table detail order like this when joined 2 tables in laravel?

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#194 ▼
    +"order_id": 37
    +"order_code": "Order00003"
    +"user_id": 1
    +"full_name": "Duc.VUong"
    +"phone": "01203388870"
    +"address": "445/33b bình đông"
    +"recieve_address": "445/33b bình đông"
    +"total_product": 2
    +"total_price": 1450000.0
    +"status": 0
    +"created_at": "2017-04-12 17:01:38"
    +"updated_at": "2017-04-12 17:01:38"
    +"detail":[
    0=>{
        +"product_id": 1
        +"price": 800000.0
        +"quantity": 1
        +"total_amount": 800000.0
    }
    1=>{
        +"product_id": 2
        +"price": 650000.0
        +"quantity": 1
        +"total_amount": 650000.0
    }
    ] 
  }
]
```

Comment: did you finded your answer?

Comment: Hi @Tauras, i found the answer. After that, how can i get data from array of array object?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387248/get-data-from-array-of-array-object-in-laravel